# SyntaxError: Unexpected token =

Tags: javascript, node.js

подскажите пожалуйста при запуске данного кода мне выдаётся ошибка

```
/var/www/pattern/lesson_2/index.js:20
  static list = {
              ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
    at new Script (vm.js:80:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:274:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:326:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:664:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
```

Код писал по видео уроку, там он корректно запускается, а у меня нет, не пойму в чем дело, подскажите пожалуйста

```js
class SimpleMembership {
  constructor (name) {
    this.name = name
    this.cost = 50
  }
}
class StandardMembership {
  constructor (name) {
    this.name = name
    this.cost = 150
  }
}
class PreniumMembership {
  constructor (name) {
    this.name = name
    this.cost = 500
  }
}
class MemberFactory {
  static list = {
    simple: SimpleMembership,
    standard: StandardMembership,
    premium: PreniumMembership
  }
  create (name, type = 'simple') {
    const Membership = MemberFactory.list[type] || MemberFactory.list.simple
    const member = new Membership(name)
    member.type = type
    member.define = () => {
      console.log(`${this.name} (${this.type}): ${this.cost}`)
    }
    return member
  }
}

const factory = new MemberFactory()
const members = [
  factory.create('tim', 'simple'),
  factory.create('jess', 'premium'),
  factory.create('roy', 'standard')
]
members.forEach(m => {
  m.define()
})
```

Comment: версия какая ноды?

Comment: node version 10.15.3

Comment: Переходите на 12 ноду: https://node.green/#ESNEXT-candidate--stage-3--static-class-fields-public-static-class-fields